# Unable to add multiple products to wishlist

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a magento 1.7.2 site and in that i can only add one product to the wishlist.when i add the second then it replaces the first one.When i comment the following lines of code in model/Wishlist.php it works fine.

```
protected function _afterSave()
   {
       parent::_afterSave();
       if (null !== $this->_itemCollection) {
           //$this->getItemCollection()->save(); //commented this line
       }
       return $this;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem, this issue mostly occurs when we run Magento with 1 website and 2 stores.

In app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Wishlist.php
find:

```
public function getItemCollection()
```

and change

```
$this->_itemCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('wishlist/item_collection')
->addWishlistFilter($this)
->addStoreFilter($this->getSharedStoreIds($currentWebsiteOnly))
->setVisibilityFilter();
```

to

```
$this->_itemCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('wishlist/item_collection')
->addWishlistFilter($this)
->addStoreFilter($this->getSharedStoreIds($currentWebsiteOnly));
```

This removes the visibility filter from the items added to the wishlist and so all items added to the wishlist will display.

More details at,

https://sarfarazlaghari.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/magento-wishlist-shows-online-1-product/

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34700/wishlist-shows-only-one-item